# Cypress how to simplify my code, beforeeach?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I have this code:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=typ_pojisteni]').select('POV + HAV', {force: true}).should('have.value', '2')
        cy.get('[type="checkbox"]:visible').check().parent()
        cy.get(':checkbox').should('be.checked')
        cy.get('[type="checkbox"]:visible').uncheck().parent()
        cy.get(':checkbox:visible').should('not.to.be.checked')
        cy.get('[data-cy=typ_pojisteni]').select('POV', {force: true}).should('have.value', '0')
        cy.get('[type="checkbox"]:visible').check().parent()
        cy.get(':checkbox').should('be.checked')
        cy.get('[type="checkbox"]:visible').uncheck().parent()
        cy.get(':checkbox:visible').should('not.to.be.checked')
```

Can I write it easier? Without repeat code? Like beforeEach?

Answer (score 0):

your test does not contain duplicate lines that can be rendered and used in `beforeEach`. I would suggest at least split it in two `it` blocks to make it more readable!

```
   it('should .....', () => {
        cy.get('[data-cy=typ_pojisteni]').select('POV + HAV', { force: true }).should('have.value', '2');
        cy.get('[type="checkbox"]:visible').check().parent();
        cy.get(':checkbox').should('be.checked');
        cy.get('[type="checkbox"]:visible').uncheck().parent();
        cy.get(':checkbox:visible').should('not.to.be.checked');
    });

    it('should ....', () => {
        cy.get('[data-cy=typ_pojisteni]').select('POV', { force: true }).should('have.value', '0');
        cy.get('[type="checkbox"]:visible').check().parent();
        cy.get(':checkbox').should('be.checked');
        cy.get('[type="checkbox"]:visible').uncheck().parent();
        cy.get(':checkbox:visible').should('not.to.be.checked');
    });
```